# How to expose both React development server and websocket server with ngrok

Tags: reactjs, sockets, ngrok

I'm building an application with React, running on port 3000, that relies on a (local) server used for web socket, running on port 3001. The client-server communication works fine locally, but I got some problems when trying to expose the application with ngrok. In particular, I'm able to expose the client (on port 3000) but when the remote hosts tries to open a connection with the web socket, the client to contact the remote host's server and not mine.
Some time ago I exposed the react client with ngrok and the requests were correctly sent to my local machine, but with web sockets I'm having some troubles.

That's the code that opens the connection for the client:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');
```

while on the server I got:

```
const socket = require('socket.io');
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3001,()=> console.log('Server listening on port 3001'));

const io  = socket(server,{
    cors: { origin: "*" }
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {...}
```

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS headers in your server and local PC.
Without CORS headers, websocket's destination is same to orignal host.

Comment: hi @sungyong, can you explain how to do this? I have pretty much the same problem. I'm working with a React.js app (port 8000) + node/express/socket.io server (port 8001), tunneling 8000 on ngrok with my personal subdomain with dedicated SSL. The client app is served but socket.io doesn't go through : impossible to test the interactions between the server side and the client on iPhone or iPad (Safari or Chrome). Even Safari doesn't accept socket.io locally on my machine (through https ngrok with ssl) :(